# Canvas pixel manipulation optimization

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, web

I'm trying to do some real-time pixel manipulation (mode7-like transformations if you are interested) with canvas.

It works so: it takes a source image data that works like a frame buffer, it does some transformations and writes the result into a another 320x240 destination image data.

```
function transform() {

    var src_pointer, dest_pointer;
    var destData = dest_context.getImageData(0,0, 320, 240);
    var imgdata = destData.data;
    var sourceData= source_context.getImageData(0,0,320,240).data;


    for (var y = 0; y< 240; y++) for (var x = 0; x< 320; x++) {

        //*** DOING SOME TRANSFORMATIONS HERE, AND WRITE THE RESULT AT SX AND SY 
        //... Doesn't have impact in perfomance. Suspicious, huh?


        dest_pointer = getPointer(x,y);
        src_pointer = getPointer(sx, sy);

        imgdata[dest_pointer] = sourceData[src_pointer];
        imgdata[dest_pointer +1] = sourceData[src_pointer +1];
        imgdata[dest_pointer +2] = sourceData[src_pointer +2];
        // Alpha? Sad thing that canvas just handle 32bit image data. I don't really need it.
        imgdata[dest_pointer +3] = sourceData[src_pointer +3]; 


    }

    dest_context.putImageData(destData,0,0);
}

//Function to help map a coordinate into image data array
function getPointer(x,y) {
    return ( ( y * 320 ) + x ) * 4;
}
```

That have a poor perfomance if you execute it continuously (about 12 frames per second). Doing some profiling I discard an specific method bottleneck (getImageData and putImageData have a really little load time).

I used to think that issue was in the transformation section but the profiling throws me that the bottle neck was specifically in the pixel assignment. Maybe optimizing math operations can be possible (think that's hard, because that's in the border line between pure javascript and browser engine), but in array assignment is possible to optimize?

Comment: Your slowdown is to be expected. `.getImageData` and `.putImageData` are expensive operations that won't support high FPS. In this case expensive means lots of data is being fetched, copied, manipulated & pushed. The GPU is not used for these operations so the process is relatively slow. If you want 3d perspective you might look at 3D canvas (webGL) for your project.

Comment: 320by240 us not that much of a load and 12 frames a second seems too slow for this. I would expect 60FPS on all but older machines. You say "poor perf... execute it continuously "  Does this mean you start with good performance then it degrades, or is the performance slow from the very first frame. If performance degrades over time your problem is else where.  (BTW there are a few improvements that can be made).

Comment: @Blindman67 Sadly, I have 12 FPS since the start. Yes, It's slow, that's why I suspect there's a obvious issue in the code that slowdowns all. Tried to find it with profiling but no sucess. (get and putData takes not much time there).